# Database connectivity in installation wizard

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, installation

I am deploying an application built using WPF. It has a Sql CE database embedded in it. Now i need to include a window in the installation wizard where the user needs to enter some information and it has to be updated in the local database with the application. im using [advanced installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) for the deployment. Can anyone here help me to sort this out please...

Comment: How can we provide help if we can't see what code you have written thus far..??

Comment: i am done with the application... i need to know how to put a new window inside the installation wizard so that i could get some details from the user like.. 
Name email company etc.. and to store these in database on the installation wizard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can learn how to capture the user input from the [Advanced Installer Tutorials](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-dialog-editor.html). To update the database with the user input you can use the [SQL Scripts replacements support from Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-custom-property-in-script.html).